# Редирект всех страниц на главную, кроме

Tags: .htaccess, apache

В корневом каталоге расположен файл index.php и конфигурационный файл .htaccess. Как правильно прописать 301 редирект со всех URL'ов на / (главную страницу), кроме URL'а со строкой http://mysite.loc/send и http://mysite.loc/?

Например:

```
http://mysite.loc/ (URL доступен)
http://mysite.loc/send (URL доступен)
http://mysite.loc/qwerty (301 редирект на /)
```

Проблема заключается в бесконечных перенаправлениях на главную страницу.

Примечание: необходимо прописать правила только в конфигурационный файл .htaccess, PHP-скрипты использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо добавить исключение через `Request_url` и настроить переадресацию со всех внутренних страниц на главную:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/send/.*$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !(^$|.*\.(css|jpg|gif)) / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Это работает, но необходимо чтобы http://mysite.loc/send отображал тоже самое, что и главная (/send это не отдельная страница).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, @Legionary! Третий день сижу